Unable to generate REST interfaces in Go for OpenAPI v3 using oapi-codegen
Is there a way to use tags (or another method) to generate interfaces in Go using oapi-codegen? I've tried:
paths:
  /foobar:
    post:
      tags:
        - FooInterface
      operationId: createFoo
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
      responses:
        201:
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'

Also:
tags:
  - name: foo
    description: Operations about foo
    x-oapi-codegen-server-interface-tag: FooInterface
  - name: bar
    description: Operations about bar
    x-oapi-codegen-server-interface-tag: BarInterface

but without any luck. Instead oapi-codgen generates a single "ServerInterface", necessitating implementation of a single controller.
